# Colleague cursing while another is on the phone

Tags: professionalism, work-environment

How would I break the ice to a colleague that needs to be reminded to not curse while another colleague near them is on the phone? I'm sure it came out naturally, which I don't mind, but I'd like to just to remind her to be more careful when she does it.

Comment: Do you talk to customers frequently, or only occasionally?  Can you hold those conversations in a private space?  If so, it behooves you to do that.

Comment: I would use some subtlety.  Unfortunately most folks here think that means lying.  I disagree.

Comment: I took everyone's advice into consideration and went the subtle route since that's how I'd like to be approached if I made a mistake. Thanks for the tips everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just tell them exactly like you wrote it in your question. I don't think most people would be offended by that especially since you have a valid reason for bringing it up that they will understand.

Answer (score 15):

Honestly, this is 100% about professionalism. "Please stop cursing when I or someone else is on the phone with a client. It makes us all sound like idiots".

Comment: Sounds quıte agressıve

Comment: Perhaps. But there are things that might be OK in some workplaces or situations but not others and those can be addressed in more delicate way. Then there are things that are just universally wrong (like cursing in front of customers) and I feel those needs a more unambiguous and direct approach.